# Make Flex-container (which inside another Flex-container) responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why, when decreasing the height of the external container, does the height of the `top-container` and its elements (`# first`, `# second`,`# third`) not decrease?

Moreover, if you set the height directly for the `top-container` element, then the nested elements are still compressed ...

How to make a flex container with its descendants nested in another flex container shrink? :)

Height of items of `.top-container` must be 120px by default, but must shrink to 40px if it needed.

```css
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 450px;
}

.top-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  background: rgba(200,0,0,.5);
}

.top-container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 1 120px;
  min-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottom-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: none;
  
  background: rgba(0,200,0,.5);
}

.bottom-container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="top-container">
    <div id="first">111</div>
    <div id="second">222</div>
    <div id="third">333</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-container">
    <div id="four">4</div>
    <div id="five">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've only set 3 dimensions in the "flex: 0 1 120px;" part and also is missing a unit on the 1, 0 can be used with no units but 1 must have a unit specified. I would suggest using css Calc combined with min-height, max height and units such as vh, vw, vmin and vmax as these are natively 'responsive'.. also why in the bottom container have you set display flex, but then stated flex none?

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
`flex: 0 1 120px` is shorthand for
`flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 120px;`
(see https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property)

Sure, i am will try `calc` and viewport properties, but i want to know where is problem in this flexbox approach :)

Comment: Ok, got ya. You've set flex direction to be column, are you expecting the items dimensions to shrink as hardcoding them with pixel values will not work like this?

Comment: `min-height:0` to top and bottom container